# Rehydrating fluent nhibernate configured DateTime as Kind Utc rather than Unspecified

Tags: nhibernate, datetime, utc

Is there a way in fluent nhibernate to map a DateTime to rehydrate my entity with DateTime.Kind set to Utc rather than unspecified? I'm currently persisting a DateTime that is Utc, but the Kind coming back is always Unspecified, throwing off my time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This isn't specific to fluent, but is fundamental to the NHibernate mapping. We use an interceptor to specify the Kind. It is similar to the approach [in this blog post](http://www.milkcarton.com/blog/2007/01/19/NHibernate%20DateTime%20And%20UTC.aspx) which lists a couple alternatives. There is also a [proposed patch (NH-1135)](http://216.121.112.228/browse/NH-1135) for handling UtcDateTime and LocalDateTime natively. I'd encourage you to vote for it.

```
public class InterceptorBase : EmptyInterceptor
{
    public override bool OnLoad(object entity, object id, object[] state,
        string[] propertyNames, IType[] types)
    {
        ConvertDatabaseDateTimeToUtc(state, types);
        return true;
    }

    private void ConvertDatabaseDateTimeToUtc(object[] state, IList<IType> types)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < types.Count; i++)
        {
            if (types[i].ReturnedClass != typeof(DateTime))
                continue;

            DateTime? dateTime = state[i] as DateTime?;

            if (!dateTime.HasValue)
                continue;

            if (dateTime.Value.Kind != DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
                continue;

            state[i] = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime.Value, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to add to this that you need to pass this object into the NHibernate session before it will be used.

return factory.OpenSession();

changed to 

return factory.OpenSession(new InterceptorBase());

Comment: The referenced link no longer works, but the content can still be found here: http://www.milkcarton.com/blog/CategoryView,category,NHibernate.aspx

Comment: I just discovered that this approach doesn't work with DateTime properties on a Component :-(.

Comment: Proposed link is dead, new one: https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1135
The patch's status is `fixed` in v3.0.0.Alpha2

Answer (score 40):

As of Nhibernate 3.0, using FluentNHibernate, you can do the following:

```
Map(x => x.EntryDate).CustomType<UtcDateTimeType>();
```

No need to use interceptors anymore.

Comment: A note of caution: `UtcDateTimeType` forces DateTimeKind to Utc. If you save a local time, say 13:30 UTC-3, then it will load the time as 13:30 UTC (without offset). I recommend to manually convert all local times to Utc using `ToUniversalTime()` or to implement a "`CustomUtcDateTimeType`" to automatically manage this case.

Comment: Also note that this only applies to the `datetime` sql type, not the `timestamp` sql type. For the latter there is an open work item: https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2520

Comment: Is it possible to register a global custom type for all DateTimes? If not, how can I unit test, if someone forgets to use the custom type?

Comment: This solution seem to cause me some trouble. 
Lets say my local time is 13:30 GMT+1. When stored in the database using this type, it is correctly stored as 12.30 UTC. When I retrieve this date from the database I get the date 13.30 UTC. If this is serialized by e.g. WebAPI, it is serialized as 13.30Z and thus when I localize it in the client-code the date becomes 14.30 GMT+1. Is there any way around this?

Comment: I had a suspicion that the behavior described in my previous comment was database specific. I used SQLite initially, as I always do for prototyping, but changing to SQL Server made this strange behavior disappear. Still an issue when I use SQLite in memory during unit tests.

Comment: @Impero did you find any solution to that SQLite specific issue? I have the same problem...

Comment: @DELUXEnized I kinda found a solution. I wrote a custom UtcDateTimeType, specifically for SQLite and added overriding rules for the mapping when I used SQLite. It worked, but it wasn't pretty.

Comment: @Impero If you put DateTimeFormat=Ticks in the connection string, it will work. However, this moves the not nice part into the sqlite database, since all DateTimes will saved as ticks. If you only use sqlite for unit testing, this is good enough.

Comment: @DELUXEnized Nice catch. I will keep that in mind. Yes, for testing that is a perfectly valid solution.

Answer (score 4):

Due to @DPeden's answer, and the comment by @Ricardo_Stuven seeming to have slight confusion, I thought I would construct this example:

Having:

```
Map(x => x.EntryDate).CustomType<LocalDateTimeType>();
```

Is the same as having: *(This code is meant to be illustrative, it is NOT an example to follow)*

```
Map(x => x._hiddenEntryDate).Column("EntryDate");
Ignore(x => x.EntryDate);

///...

public class MyEntity
{
    protected virtual DateTime _hiddenEntryDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EntryDate
    {
        get
        {
            return DateTime.SpecifyKind(_hiddenEntryDate, DateTimeKind.Local);
        }
        set
        {
            _hiddenCreated = DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Local);
        }
    }
}
```

Namely, it NEVER calls `.ToLocalTime()`, whatever you pass into it, or get out of it, is assumed to represent localtime, it is not enforced to be, it does not recognize that the developer would ever use DateTimeKind correctly.

Similarly `UtcDateTimeType` never calls `.ToUniversalTime()`