# Fluent Nhibernate - configure all dates to be rehydrated from UTC

Tags: datetime, nhibernate, configuration, fluent-nhibernate, utc

This SO question talks about ["Rehydrating fluent nhibernate configured DateTime as Kind Utc rather than Unspecified"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547133/rehydrating-fluent-nhibernate-configured-datetime-as-kind-utc-rather-than-unspec).

One of the later answers in that question has this:

```
Map(x => x.EntryDate).CustomType<UtcDateTimeType>();
```

That works for one property on one entity.

I would like to know if there is a way to specify that ALL datetime properties are stored as UTC in the database.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way with fluent NHibernate is **`Convention`**

#### [Conventions](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Conventions)

*James Gregory edited this page on 3 Apr 2012 · 1 revision*

> ...
>   The conventions are built using a set of interfaces and base classes that each define a single method, Apply, with varying parameters based on the kind of convention you're creating; this method is where you make the changes to the mappings.
>   ...

Drafted example:

```
public class UtcConvention : IPropertyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        if (instance.Type.Name == "Date")
        {
            instance.CustomType<UtcDateTimeType>();
        }
    }
}
```

We have to add this into configuration

```
FluentMappings
  .Conventions.Add(new UtcConvention())
```

Comment: That worked my friend. Very elegant solution. Thank you.

Comment: Great to see that, really. Enjoy awesome NHibernate, sir ;)

Answer (score 5):

Hi Thanks for the answer Radim,

I have to make some minor changes to you code to get it to work and support nullable **DateTime?** properties.

```
    public class UtcConvention : IPropertyConvention  {
        public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance) {
            if (instance.Type.Name == "DateTime" || instance.Type.ToString().StartsWith("System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime")) {
                instance.CustomType<UtcDateTimeType>();
            }
        }
    }
```

Maybe this might help someone else looking for a solution

Answer (score 1):

Hate magic strings.

```
using FluentNHibernate.Conventions;
using FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Instances;
using NHibernate.Type;
using System;

namespace MyAwesomeApp
{
    public class UTCDateTimeConvention : IPropertyConvention
    {
        public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
        {
            var type = instance.Type.GetUnderlyingSystemType();

            if (type == typeof(DateTime) || type == typeof(DateTime?))
            {
                instance.CustomType<UtcDateTimeType>();
            }
        }
    }
}
```